# jQuery toggle to work with ajax load more

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this jQuery script to be able to show/hide information from posts on an archive page:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 200;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "See more";
    var lesstext = "See less";
    

    $('.quote').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="more"><span class="more-content">' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="toggle-more button">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".toggle-more").click(function(){
        
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().slideToggle('50','swing');
        return false;
    });
});
```

at the same time I'm using an Ajax script to be able to load more posts. The problem is that the toggle code above is just getting applied on the first "page" of posts. I guess it might have something to do with "$(document).ready(function()".. Is there another way to initialize  the function so that the toggle script is not just applied on document ready but also is "listening" if any more posts are getting loaded?

EDIT ----------------------------------------------
Ok, so I need to add the toggle-more button after content has been loaded. I was thinking I could use the `$('.quote').each(function()` that I had in my original post and also add it to my function for `$('body').on('click', '.load-more', function(e)` as well, but I can't get it to work.

```
jQuery(function($){ 

var page = 2;   
var $clients_grid = $('.client-reviews');
        $clients_grid.isotope({
          // options
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
          percentPosition: false,
          transitionDuration: '0s', 
          hiddenStyle: {
            opacity: 0
          },
          visibleStyle: {
            opacity: 1
          }
});
        

$('body').on('click', '.load-more', function(e) {

        var data_clients = {
            'action': 'load_clients_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_clients"); ?>'
          };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data_clients, function(response){
            if (response.replace(/^\s*$/, "").length == 0) {
              $('.load-more').text("<?php printf( __( 'No more results', 'bizniz-tools' )); ?>");
              $('.load-more').attr("disabled", true);
              $('.load-more').css("borderColor", "rgba(214, 213, 210, 1)");
              $('.load-more').css("background-color", "inherit");   
              $('.load-more').css("color", "rgba(214, 213, 210, 1)");   
              
            } else {
              var $clients_answer = $(response);

              //append items to grid
              $clients_grid.append($clients_answer)
              .isotope('appended', $clients_answer);

              // layaout on imagesLoaded
              $clients_grid.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $clients_grid.isotope('layout');
              });
              page++;
            }
          });
    
    
     $('.quote').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="more"><span class="more-content">' + h + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="" class="toggle-more button">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    }); 
          e.preventDefault();
    }); 
    
    
});
```

What can I do to make the quote-function get executed every time I hit the `.load-more` button?

Comment: Try: `$(document, '.toggle-more').click(/*...*/);`. See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `$(document, ` to the button event didn't solve the problem. Now the .toggle-more buttons makes the page reload instead. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will need to replace instances of `$(this)` within the function handler with `$(event.target)`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cmzqL7t5/

Comment: ok, so now I've tried to update the toggle-more click function with `$(event.target)` instead of `$(this)`. but somehow it ONLY affects the load more function and not the toggle buttons. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "ONLY affects the load more function".

Comment: When I added `$(event.target)` to the `.toggle-more` button, the load more button (called `.load-more`) was the one that got affected and started to behave like a toggle instead of loading more posts. Could it be that the posts that uses the toggle function is loaded with the load more function?

Comment: If you share a relevant snippet of your HTML I might be able to help you.

Comment: Tried to add a snippet on JSFiddle but its hard to replicate the problem since I need to load more posts from database. But I have opened up my dev site for you to have a look; [link](https://doodev.se/bizniztools/) 

If you scroll down to the yellow section, there's various "Se mer" buttons and also a "Läs in fler" button. If you hit the "Läs mer" button, more posts will be loaded. But the new posts won't have the toggle button "Se mer" since they were not there on "document ready" (I assume that's the problem?). Hope this makes it a bit easier to understand :)

Comment: @76484 I have now updated my original post with some more content. Would be awesome if you could please have a look!

Comment: I don't think I will be able to help you. It is unclear to me what the problem is. I don't know if the issue is to do with the `.toggle-more` button, the `.load-more` button or the `.quote` truncating (or perhaps a combination of these).

Comment: Ok, I understand. To me, it feels like it has to do with that the `.toggle-more` button is being added in the `.quote` function on `$(document).ready` and not whenever more posts is being loaded dynamically into new .quote divs when click on `.load-more`. Wish I would be able to show a snippet but I don't know how when there's dynamic content involved.

Comment: Perhaps this simplified example can help set you on the right track: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/hj90xmnb/